# Get C# List in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I created a list in my c# code and I tried to send it to a JavaScript function:

**.aspx.cs code:**

```
List<SomeObject> data = whatever.getList();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "test('" + data + "');", true);
```

**.js:**

```
function test(data) {
```

The data variable in my JavaScript function is a string like:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeObject]"
```

How can I pass this variable from my aspx page to my .js file and read what is inside it?

Comment: You have to serialize your data

Comment: You can pass the list as comma separated string by 
string data = YourList.Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y); and then split that string by javascript to fulfill your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass convert it to json:

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "test('" + jsonSerialiser.Serialize(data)+ "');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call RegisterStartupScript method .net executes data variables `ToString()` methods and render javascript to page. Result of `List<SomeObject>.ToString()` method returns `"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeObject]"` so that you cannot use variable in javasciprt

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "test('" + data + "');", true);
```

You must serialize your List to json list first [like this](http://json.codeplex.com/documentation) and pass it to RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** dont know what is `list<T>`. you have to convert it to **JSON**.beacause javascript only `recognizes` JSON

Answer (score 0):

First thought come to my mind is to use JSON template.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list into a JSON array, like this (pseudo-code, is it c#??)

```
var json = "[";
foreach(elem in data) {
  json += "'" + elem.toString() + "', ";
}
json += "]";
```

than add the json instead of the data in your code.